# Why is the U variable set to NULL in this interesting Javascript code fragment?

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript code fragment as

```
var u = {};
var x = y = z = {"cvalue":"cell", "call":function(){alert(this.cvalue);}};

(function(){u=x;/*change all cvalue in x,y, z, u*/ u.cvalue = "notcell";})();

if(u == x && x == y && y == z && z == u){
    u.call();
}

//only u goes to null
u = null;
//x,y,z stay same
alert(x.cvalue);
```

wondering why `u = null` only applies for `u`?

Comment: Is there a question behind the question? Because the first one makes very little sense...

Comment: not really a question. just playing around with javascript.

Comment: Also note that there is a Javascript method called [ **`call`** ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), so that nomenclature is quite confusing.

Comment: Be careful with the `var x = y = z = ...` pattern, only `x` is an actually declared variable, `y` and `z` are simply assignments to *undeclared* identifiers. For example, if you put that code in a function, only `x` will be bound to that local scope, `y` and `z` will become properties of the global object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables don't actually hold an object, but simply hold a reference to one. By assigning `u` to `null`, you're dropping the reference that `u` had to the object.

A more basic example:

```
var x = { 'name': 'Bob' };
var y = x;

console.log(x);   //  Object { name="Bob"}
console.log(y);   //  Object { name="Bob"}

y.name = 'Jack';

console.log(x);   //  Object { name="Jack"}
console.log(y);   //  Object { name="Jack"}

x = null;

console.log(x);   //  null
console.log(y);   //  Object { name="Jack"}
```

Note how our object isn't held in `x`. It's held somewhere in memory, and `x` is referring to it. When we do `y = x`, we copy the reference to `y`, and therefore `y` begins to refer to the same object. Setting `x` to `null` simply drops the reference that `x` holds to the object, leaving the actual object unaffected. If we were to set `y` to `null`, or to anything else, the garbage collector would eventually pick up the object for destruction.

Comment: just curious. how about if i do x=y=z... x=u; u=x;?

Comment: @jebberwocky: when you do x=y=z= something, you only say that x,y,z should point to the same thing, not copies. Say you have a piece of paper, and let your friends z, y and z point to it. If someone writes something on that piece of paper everyone will see it. Compare this to if you give each a different piece of paper with the same text on it. If x writes something on his paper, the others will not see it.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right, but you have to be careful because in Javascript you are sometimes dealing with a copy, and othertimes dealing with the original. For example...

```
var a = new Object();
a.foo = new function(){alert("I exist")};

var b = a;

b.foo = null;//this erases the function from both a and b (technically, there is only one since a and b point to the same place in memory).

a.foo();//this now fails since there is no longer a function called foo

b = null;//this does NOT affect a in any way as per Daneiel Vassallo's explanation.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the exact same object to x, y and z, not a copy of it's value, but the exact same object.

In pseudo code:

```
var u = OBJECT_A // u points to OBJECT_A

var x = y = z = OBJECT_B // x y and z points to OBJECT_B

(function(){
    u=x;  // Drop reference to OBJECT_A and point to OBJECT_B

    /*change all cvalue in x,y, z, u*/
    u.cvalue = "notcell";  //Changes the cvalue in OBJECT_B
                           // Remember x,y,z, and u points to OBJECT B
                           // so x.cvalue, y.cvalue, z.cvalue and u.cvalue is the same
})();

if(u == x && x == y && y == z && z == u){
   u.call();
}

//only u goes to null
u = null;  // Drop reference to OBJECT_B and point to NULL.


//x,y,z still points to OBJECT_B
alert(x.cvalue);
```

Comment: what happen if set x= null instead of u = null?

Comment: x, y, z and u just points to the object. when you set x=null you just say that x should point to null instead of the object. Lets say you have a book and put it on the table. Then you tell your friends x, y, z and u to point at the book and all of them does. If you tell x to write something on page 42, and then ask y whats on page 42, you get what x wrote on that page. Then you tell u to point at nothing. But x,y,z still points at the same book.